# customtkinter window not responding when I un-focus the window during a loop

Tags: python, opencv, user-interface, tkinter, customtkinter

I am using customtkinter to build a UI for my program that turns each frame of an input mp4 file into an image and saves it in an output folder. Here is the code that I have so far:

```py
import customtkinter as ctk
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import Image
import tkinter.filedialog as fd
import cv2
import random

files = ''
folder = ''
totalFrames = 0
videoFrames = []

ctk.set_appearance_mode("Dark")

ctk.set_default_color_theme("green")

root = ctk.CTk()
appWidth, appHeight = 780, 840, 
monWidth, monHeight = (root.winfo_screenwidth()-appWidth), (root.winfo_screenheight()-appHeight)

root.geometry(f"{appWidth}x{appHeight}")#+{monWidth}+{monHeight}")

def addFiles():
    global files
    global videoFrames
    global totalFrames
    videoFrames=[]
    totalFrames=0
    files = ''

    #OPEN FILE EXPLORER AND STORES FILENAMES IN LIST
    files = fd.askopenfilenames(parent=root, title='Add Video Files',filetypes=[('Video Files',".mp4")])

    for i in range(len(files)):
        #VIDEO VARIABLE
        currentCap = cv2.VideoCapture(files[i])
        
        #STORE FRAME COUNT OF VIDEOS 
        videoFrames.append(int(currentCap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT)))
        #print(videoFrames)

        #STORE TOTAL FRAMES IN ALL VIDEOS SELECTED
        totalFrames = int(currentCap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT)) + totalFrames
        #print(totalFrames)
        


def output():
    #OPEN FILE EXPLORER AND STORES OUTPUT FOLDER SELECTION IN VARIABLE
    global folder
    folder = fd.askdirectory(parent=root, title='Select Output Folder')


def process():
    global currentVideoFrameTotal
    global totalVideoFrameTotal
    global currentPercent
    global totalPercent
    totalVideoFrameTotal = 1

    if folder and files:
        for i in range(len(files)):
            cap = cv2.VideoCapture(files[i])
            currentVideoFrameTotal = 1
            currentPercent = 0

            while True:
                currentPercent = round((currentVideoFrameTotal / videoFrames[i]), 2)
                # print(currentPercent, 'current')
                totalPercent = round((totalVideoFrameTotal / totalFrames), 2)
                # print(totalPercent, 'total')

                success, frame = cap.read()

                if success:
                    cv2.imwrite(f'{folder}\\Video{i}Frame{currentVideoFrameTotal}.jpg', frame)

                else:
                    break
            
                currentVideoFrameTotal = currentVideoFrameTotal + 1
                totalVideoFrameTotal = totalVideoFrameTotal + 1

                vidProg.set(currentPercent)
                totalProg.set(totalPercent)
                root.update_idletasks()

                #print(f'File #{i}  -  Current: {currentVideoFrameTotal}%  -  Total: {totalVideoFrameTotal}%', end="\r")

            cap.release()

                


    if not folder and files:
        print('Please Select an output folder')

    if not files and folder:
        print('Please select video files for processing')

    if not files and not folder:
        print('Please select video files to process and an output folder')


addFile = ctk.CTkButton(master=root, text='add', command=addFiles)
addFile.pack(pady=10)

startProcess = ctk.CTkButton(master=root, text='start', command=process)
startProcess.pack(pady=10)

outputFolder = ctk.CTkButton(master=root, text='output', command=output)
outputFolder.pack(pady=10)

vidProg = ctk.CTkProgressBar(master=root, width=appWidth * .85, height=30)
vidProg.pack(pady=10)
vidProg.set(0.0)

totalProg = ctk.CTkProgressBar(master=root, width=appWidth * .85, height=30)
totalProg.pack(pady=10)
totalProg.set(0.0)

root.mainloop()
```

The problem is that if I start the processing and then unfocus the window, the program shows a "Not responding" message and doesn't update the progress bars that I have. Can someone help me solve this issue?